# Snoidal wave solutions of the $\phi^4$ model

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, wave-equation, elliptic-functions

I want to prove the existence of snoidal wave solutions of the $\phi^4$ model, given by
$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=u-u^3,\; (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}.$$

So, we are looking for solutions in the form $u(x, t) = \varphi_c(x−ct),
$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Substituting into the $\phi^4$ model and integrating once, we obtain
$$\varphi'^2=\frac{1}{w}\left(\frac{\varphi^4}{2}-\varphi^2+2a\right),$$
where $\varphi:= \varphi_c$,$w:=1-c^2>0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant of integration. Therefore,
$$\varphi'^2=\frac{1}{w}\frac{1}{2}\left(\varphi^2-B_1^2)(\varphi^2-B_2^2\right),$$
where $B_1^2=1+\sqrt{1-4a}, B_2^2=1-\sqrt{1-4a}$, with $a<\frac{1}{4}$. Hence,
$$\frac{d\varphi}{ds}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2w}}\sqrt{\left(\varphi^2-B_1^2)(\varphi^2-B_2^2\right)} \Rightarrow\frac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{\left(\varphi^2-B_1^2)(\varphi^2-B_2^2\right)}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2w}} \; ds.$$

I thought about integrating this last equality and using, somehow, the formula $ 216.00 $ of $ [1] $ in order to obtain the snoidal solution sought, but I don't know how to proceed and if I can use this formula. Moreover, what I did is correct?

$[1]$ P.F.Byrd, M.D.Friedman. Hand Book of Elliptical Integrals for Engineers and Scientis. Springer-Verlag-New York-Heidelberg-Berlin, 1971.

Comment: Just to comment that a very good modern exposition to this equation may be found here: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030118389, Keverkidis & Cuevas-Maraver, A Dynamical Perspective on the $\phi ^4$ Model, Springer 2019

Comment: @AmirSagiv Thanks!